Can I force Fleet to use a specific Gradle build?
The Fleet is currently creating a gradle wrapper (gradlew) for use in the project. IDEA (like Android Studio) has a setting that allows you to select a specific Gradle assembly (or use a wrapper).





I can’t find such an assembly in Fleet. Is there such a thing? Are there any plans to add it if not?

Fleet uses Gradle, configured in the project configuration files. E.g. Gradle, which is specified in gradle-wrapper.properties. So, please use Gradle configuration means to set up Gradle version for the project. E.g in gradle-wrapper.properties file set the
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.7-bin.zip


This is a description of how to configure the Gradle wrapper version. There is no problem with this. In the question, I specifically clarified that I am interested in the case when a specific Gradle assembly is used instead of a wrapper, how can IDEA or Android Studio do this.
